# How to make a JavaFX TRANPARENT/UNDECORATED Window draggable by Controller?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I´m trying to make my JavaFX transparent Sub-Window draggable **by Controller** (and FXML).
I already archieved it to make it draggable by AnotherWindow.java like that:

```
public class AnotherWindow {
double yOffset; double xOffset;

Stage anotherStage = new Stage();
public AnotherWindow(String fxml) {
    try {
        Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("../application/application.css").toExternalForm());


        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            if(event.)
            xOffset = anotherStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
            yOffset = anotherStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
        });
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            anotherStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
            anotherStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
        });

        anotherStage.setResizable(false);
        anotherStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        anotherStage.setScene(scene);
        anotherStage.setTitle("Control Panel(AutoClicker)");
        anotherStage.getScene().setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        anotherStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        anotherStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The reason why I want to make it draggable by Controller, is that I want to move the Window by dragging a button and not by dragging the whole scene/window.

Hope you can help me! (sorry for my bad english, I´m quite young)
~Henri

Comment: Pass an instance of your stage to the Controller and install a drag listener to your respective button

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. How can I get my stage into the controller?

Comment: figured it out ! :D thanks

Comment: There's typically no need to pass the stage to the controller. In an event handler, you can do `Window window = someNode.getScene().getWindow()` where `someNode` is any node contained in the scene (so your button would suffice). It's probably enough to have  a `Window` reference, since all you want to do is move it, but if you really need a `Stage` you can downcast it.